# Using Python Regex how can I specify beginning and/or end word and only any digits in the middle?

Tags: python, regex

I need to match 'words' (string of characters with no spaces) that might have the word **near** at the beginning and/or the end and have **only** digits in the middle.
Examples: near3 4near near2near
It should not match words like nearing3 4nearsighted near3ness nearsighted

I tried this: `x = re.match(r"((\bnear)|(near\b))(\d)", txt)`
It works for this word: near3 and this word: near4near but not for this word 2near

Answer (score 0):

You can match optional `near` followed by digits and `near` OR match `near` and  digits using an alternation using the pipe `|`

You can surround the alternation with a non capture group and add word boundaries `\b` at both sides of the pattern to prevent a partial word match.

If you want to match a single digit, you can use only `\d` instead.

```
\b(?:(?:near)?\d+near|near\d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZH55LL/1)